# Ui-router switching back to home state (url:"") doesn't change the url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Problem is that if I change back to `index` view with `url: ""` from any other state, the page content changes but not the url.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('index', {
        url: "",
        views: {
            ...
        }
    })
    .state('route1', {
        url: "/route1",
        views: {
            ...
        }
    })
```

So imagine being on `*.com/route1` and clicking on the navbar logo back to `index`. The url still displays `.com/route1` although I would expect the url to be `.com`.

I wanted to create a plunker, but there was no need since one of the most popular templates there already has the same issue: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:SDOcGS?p=preview).

To see the issue you must go to preview mode from the top right corner (blue button). And go to `Route 1` and back to `Home`. Look at the url.

---

I am quite sure that this has been asked somewhere but unfortunately I am not able to come up with the correct search term to find an answer.

---

**Is this an issue with ui-router? Are there any known fixes to this problem?**

Comment: Do you know that `/#/` is appended at the end of your domain to show its a SPA. You can easily achieve this using `.state('index', {
        url: "/", //add / here
        views: {
            ...
        }`

Comment: Although I'm not sure what you are trying to tell me I have HTML5Mode set to true. So the `/#/` doesn't apply in my case. Also as I commented below: But then sometimes for a state like `index.something` I would then have to define urls as `something` and most of the time for simple cases as `/something`. If I were to use the wrong syntax in the url I would get either double slashes: `//something/something` or a missing slash in between: `/somethingsomething`. But this is already an incosistency when defining new states - which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I'm gonna solve this by making some "root" state urls absolute as described in this answer: [Angular UI Router - Dynamic states get double slashes when navigated to with ui-sref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25498491/1016777).

Ui-router absolute states: [Absolute Routes (^)](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#absolute-routes-)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to define the url as "/" rather than "". Updated plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/aLVguiCtvAr3JIM8RbbO?p=preview)

```
$stateProvider
.state('index', {
    url: "/",
    views: {
        ...
    }
})
.state('route1', {
    url: "/route1",
    views: {
        ...
    }
})
```

Comment: But then sometimes for a state like `index.something` I would then have to define urls as `something` and for simple cases as `/something`. If I were to use the wrong syntax in the url, I would get either double slashes `//something/something` or without a slash `/somethingsomething`. But this is already an incosistency when defining new states. Do you know of any other way to solve the problem whilst keeping the index url as it is `""`?

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not sure what you mean. Can you demonstrate your concerns in a plunker?

Comment: I tried to come up with one, although it is hard to keep it simple at the same time. But maybe this will show the inconsisteny what I'm talking about. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UIGFGrpU1uRw3qGl2yaB?p=preview). I tried adding some comments which might help to understand the problem.

Comment: Ahh... Now I know what you mean.. the problem is arising only because you have "/" as the url for the parent view (index). If the url had been "home" or something, it would have worked fine, as shown here - http://plnkr.co/edit/sKQ90LHy8fxeHNunnzwT?p=preview. Sorry,  but I am not sure how to get around this without introducing the above-mentioned inconsistencies.